# Laravel 5.6 view composer giving Error Argument 2 passed with() must be callable or null

Tags: laravel

I need little support here

I am using laravel 5.6. I want to populate sidebar of my blog with View Composer. It is giving me error from sidebarComposer file. I don't know what am I doing wrong. Please note that I have registered this provider in config->app.php file. The error is

> **ERROR:** Argument 2 passed to with() must be callable or null, array given,
>   called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\LaraSite2\app\Http\Composers\SidebarComposer.php on
>   line 13

### SidebarComposer.php

```
<?php        
        namespace App\Http\Composers;
        use App\Post;
        use App\User;
        use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;


        class SidebarComposer {        
            public function compose(View $view){        
                $view-with('posts', Post::all());//This line is giving error
            }

        }
```

### SidebarComposerProvider.php

```
class SidebarComposerProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //Register composeSidebar funtion
        $this->composeSidebar();
    }
    public function composeSidebar(){
        view()->composer('layouts.aside','App\Http\Composers\SidebarComposer');
    }
}
```

### layout for Sidebar (layouts.aside)

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
          <div class="blog-posts"><a href="#">
              <div class="item d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="image"><img src="img/small-thumbnail-1.jpg" alt="..." class="img-fluid"></div>
              <div class="title"><strong>{{$post->title}}}</strong>
                  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <div class="views"><i class="icon-eye"></i> 500</div>
                    <div class="comments"><i class="icon-comment"></i>12</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div></a>
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a syntax mistake with your code SidebarComposer

```
$view-with('posts', Post::all());
```

use syntax

```
$view->with('posts', Post::all());
```

Comment: @ShaieIndra Gupta  haha I think I should take some rest for a while. Thanks its working now